# Android sdk. Send bytes directly to videoview/Mediaplayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-view, android-sdk-2.3, android-video-player

I need to play Matroska (.mkv) video but Android VideoView doesn't support that container.

In order to play a video I need to set the source to a file.

What I want to know is if I can send bytes directly from the video and send it directly to videoview or mediaPlayer?

If I can't then I can save these bytes to a file and have videoview play/read them even without metadata?

Thanks,